# Position fixed not working with video poster

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a div at the right side, superimposed to a video tag element which has a poster attribute but for any reason, when I set the property `right: 0` to align it at the right side, it is aligned to the right side of the document.

```
<div class="screen-container">
   <div id="delete"></div>
   <video id="preview"></video>
</div>

#screen-container{
   width: 515px;
   height: 600.23px;
}
#delete {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: white;
   background-size: 500px;
   background-position: -97px -75px;
   margin: 10px 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
}
#preview{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

I have also tested to put the `<div id="delete>` inside the `<video>` but the `<div>` element wasn't vissible.

```
<div class="screen-container">
   <video id="preview">
      <div id="delete"></div>
   </video>
</div>
```

Any idea of what is happening?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fixed` positioning removes the element from the flow of the document and can not be contained within a parent. Use `position: absolute` instead and set the parent `.screen-container` to `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of jmore009, I had a problem with elements that were comming behind. 
To solve that other case, I just added did what I show at the code below:

```
<div class="screen-container">
   <div id="delete"></div>
   <video id="preview"></video>
</div>
<div class="screen-aux"></div>

.screen-container{
   position: absolute;
}

#delete{
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: white;
   background-size: 500px;
   background-position: -97px -75px;
   margin: 10px 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   right: 0;
}
```

That allows me to add vissible elements behind by keep using position relative.

Thanks!